# nodejs Express regex path: working in test, not working in code. What do I do wrong?

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I want a super simple filter in nodejs express routing path. The param must be word1 or word2. 
Tested in: https://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

with expression: test/:gender(\b(word1|word2)\b)

path: test/word2

And all works well. "The path matches the route"

But in code:

```
router.get('^/test/:gender(\b(word1|word2)\b)', function (req, res, next){//something})...;
```

I got 404(redirects from express, as it should if the param is not correct!).

Note 1: removing the regex string, it works.

Note 2: another filter I DID managed to make it work. It has to be like: "word1-word2[-moreWords]. I implemented it with

```
router.get('^/test/:user_name(*[a-zA-Z0-9][-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])', function (req, res, next) {//something});
```

and works without problem.

Note 3: I also test it (I write them first in:) https://regex101.com/ and, of course, they work.

So what do I do wrong?

Comment: you may have config missing at express please provide us with express configuration like port,context

Comment: Try `'^/test/:gender(word1|word2)\\b'` or `'^/test/:gender(word1|word2)\b'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It worked! with the \\b! Great, thanks!
Now please teach me, why it works in express routing test and not in code? This was just an example but I will use many regex to prevent wrong/malicious insertions and some of them more complex. Any tips on how/where to write and test them so that they do work in code as well?
P.S. can you write it as reply so I can close the question?

Comment: @BasilBattikhi Can port influence regex? If port was wrong, I would get browser 404 (not express - as it should) on anything, right?

Comment: @SharpBCD i don't think so but u thought that you may hitting on different port

Comment: No, the only drama was with that simple regex. Working on all test/simulator but not in code. Very frustrating.
This is why I specified that other regex are working. It means all settings are correct so the problem is only in the expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
'^/test/:gender(word1|word2)\\b'
```

Note that there is no word boundary between `gender` and `word`, you can only keep the *trailing* word boundary.

To define a word boundary, you need a literal backslash followed with `b`, so inside a string literal, you should write two consecutive backslash symbols.